# Pagination issue: `map' : undefined method 'existent'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I just installed the `will_paginate, 3.0.7` and `bootstrap-will_paginate, 0.0.10` gem and when i call the following to get my articles paginated

```
def index
 @articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

I get the following error upon attempting to launch the localhost server

```
/Users/Jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:45:in `map': undefined method `existent' for #<String:0x007fd4a2bfa5d0> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  extend
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried updating `will_paginate` to use version **3.1.5** ?

Comment: Thanks @dkp why wouldn't 3.0.7 work even though it did in this tutorial I'm doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was an issue with earlier version of `will_paginate` with Rails 5.

You need to update your `will_paginate` gem to use latest updated one which is:

`gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.5'`

This issue has been fixed with this merge:
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/pull/450